# Acces a value in an entity in twig

Tags: drupal, module, twig, paragraph

[image]

I am using the paragraph module in drupal
I am trying to get acces to some values
I am able to get each paragraph object by content.field_portfolio_items.1 or 2 or 3 ... etc
I am not getting to the values inside.
I am trying to acces the value 'field_button_text'

Van anyone tell me how i get to that value using twig
 something like (this one isnt working for me):
{{ content.field_portfolio_items.2.paragraph.values.field_button_text }}

Comment: content.field_portfolio_items[2]['#paragraph'].field_button_text[0].value did it! Sure this will help others